# Call another class in apps

Tags: iphone, xcode, urbanairship.com

how do I call journalView page in ViewController viewDidLoad fragment code? i also create journalView.xib in journalView class..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.version.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UAirship Version: %@", [UAirshipVersion get]];
    [UAPush useCustomUI:[UAPushUI class]];

}
```

Comment: describe your requirement in detail.

Comment: i have edit the code..sorry im new learner for ios